# How to make string comparison exactly

Tags: php, html, css

I'm comparing URL with a string(css class) and changing the css class for particular URL's.

```
<?php $urlrequest=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>


<li <?php if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || "/PS/#pics") 
{echo "class=\"bluemenu\"";}
   else
{echo "class=\"greymenu\"";} ?>
   <span>PS Menu</span>
</li>

<li <?php if($urlrequest == "/PS/otherpages") 
{echo "class=\"bluemenu\"";}
   else
{echo "class=\"greymenu\"";} ?>
   <span>PS Menu</span>
</li>
```

I'm getting `bluemenu` for all the pages adding after /PS/ in the URL, for example. When I'm on http://website.com/PS/otherpages/ page, I expect only /PS/otherpages in blue menu and /PS/ in greymenu because /PS/ doesn't match the URL. But for both it gives bluemenu

```
http://website.com/PS/ --> bluemenu
http://website.com/PS/otherpages/ -> bluemenu
```

I have tried adding FQDN instead of /PS/

```
<?php $urlrequest= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";?>

<li <?php if($urlrequest == "http://www.website.com/PS/") 
{echo "class=\"bluemenu\"";}
   else
{echo "class=\"menu\"";} ?>
   <span>PS Menu</span>
</li>

<li <?php if($urlrequest == "http://www.website.com/PS/otherpages") 
{echo "class=\"bluemenu\"";}
   else
{echo "class=\"menu\"";} ?>
   <span>PS Menu</span>
</li>
```

Still all the pages comes after /PS/ are showing bluemenu.  How to avoid this conflict ?

Comment: You are not closing your opening `li`'s, is that just a typo here? Either way, you should add the generated html, that should give a better indication as to what the problem is.

Comment: `"http://www.website.com/PS/" == "http://www.website.com/PS/otherpages"` is `false` so are you sure that all of your other pages are `bluemenu`?

Comment: @jeroen, its a typo mistake , after modifying if statement it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your `if` statements. Instead of

```
if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || "/PS/#pics")
```

You need

```
if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || $urlrequest == "/PS/#pics")
```

The reason is because the operators `if`, `ifelse` and `else` require a boolean, and if you provide a non-boolean, it will be casted to a boolean. Since you are providing the string `"/PS/#pics"`, when that is cast to a boolean is converted to `true`, which is [the same with most strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). So  you're essentially doing:

```
if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || true)
```

Which will, of course, always be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || "/PS/#pics")
```

notice that your or statement should be:

```
if($urlrequest == "/PS/" || $urlrequest == "/PS/#pics")
```

else the string would always return as true, thus giving you the blue menu.